# Rgeo, activerecord-postgis-adapter does't fire SQL statements for attributes of type point

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, postgis, rgeo, rails-4-2-1

So I'm running `rgeo` with `activerecord-postgis-adapter` and have a Rails 4 app's db.yml file set up correctly.

But when I set the attributes of a ActiveRecord model like:

```
Place
 .create(name: 'some name', geom: RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(:srid => 4326)
 .point(latitude,longitude)
```

And then check the SQL INSERT statement it fires, it won't include `geom` in the INSERT
`INSERT INTO "places" ("name", "some_attr".....` <- no geom attr being inserted.

If anyone has seen this before and has an idea to what the problem might be, please help thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(:srid => 4326)` returns some value?

Comment: Yup! A point object is assigned as the attributes value.  When I re-query the record using `.find(id)` it's no longer there because that attribute wasn't part of the `create's` SQL INSERT